How can you have position basis and energy basis?
In Quantum Mechanics, my understanding is that we have a Hilbert space.
If we to model a particle in space we consider the space defined by the basis
$$|x\rangle$$
for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$
We then define the position operator to be the operator such that
$$\hat{x} |x\rangle = x|x\rangle$$
We can then construct a Hamiltonian operator, for example the SHO Hamiltonian
$$\hat{H} = \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2\hat{x}^2$$
This leads us to energy eigenbasis $|n\rangle$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$
But this has a different cardinality to the position eigenbasis (one is countable the other is not). So how can they both be basis for the same Hilbert space?

position "eigenbasis" does not exist. They don't live in a Hilbert space, but rather in Rigged Hilbert space. It is, however, provably fine to use them.

Does this answer your question? Are the position eigenkets $\lvert x \rangle$ really a basis for the space of states?

This exact question has been asked here more than once. Please consider using the search function first.
